# Error while returning data in wcf?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-ria-services, wcf-security

When performing GetAll_SamplePriscriptionDrug function of the error message

```
public EpriscriptionSrv()
{
using (var ctx = new EpriscriptionContext())
{
ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
LstSamplePriscriptionDrug = ctx.SamplePriscriptionDrug.ToList();
}           
}

public static List<SamplePriscriptionDrug> LstSamplePriscriptionDrug = new List<SamplePriscriptionDrug>();


[OperationContract]
public List<SamplePriscriptionDrug> GetAll_SamplePriscriptionDrug()
{
    return LstSamplePriscriptionDrug;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably an issue related to your connectivity with the service. Check the endpoint binding for your service as well. See that the ports match and connections are allowed.

Comment: Did you try accessing service in browser.

Comment: FYI it's spelled 'prescription', not 'priscription'. That's the sort of thing that does my head in.